# Can I setup an Indy node to read from the Sovrin Mainnet?

Tags: hyperledger-indy

Is it possible to setup an Indy node using the Sovrin pool's genesis files in order to read from the Sovrin mainet?

I would like to sync a node to the Sovrin mainet in order to resolve Sovrin DIDs, e.g. "did:sov:1a2b3c4d5e6f7g".  Is it possible for anyone to do this?  Or do I need special permission to connect to other nodes on the network?

If it's not possible, how would I go about resolving arbitrary DIDs?

Comment: if you want to add new node into existing indy network you would need to have steward role for that.

Comment: From what I've read, you only need to be a Steward to write to the network, and you don't need to be a steward in order to read from the network, but it seems there is another process for establishing a read-only node, I'm just not clear on that part.

Comment: with "node" you mean "indy node" right? If you want to add read-only node I think it's not implemented yet. However there is plan (https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/INDY-1010) to have Observers for having read-only nodes to reduce load on Validator nodes. If you want to browse Sovrin Main Net you can check the Ledger Browser: https://sovrin-mainnet-browser.vonx.io/browse/domain?page=1&query=7jJe9ArRfRchSKL2sYgFDj&txn_type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can talk to the Indy main-net nodes as a client. You do not need to set up your own node.

You can use the indy-cli program to talk to the validator nodes in the ledger. You need the pool genesis transactions to get connected to the pool, and then you can issue get-nym commands.

You can get the genesis transactions from [this directory](https://github.com/sovrin-foundation/sovrin/tree/master/sovrin). Then in indy-cli you will use commands like this:

```
pool create builder gen_txn_file=pool_transactions_builder_genesis
pool connect builder
ledger get-nym did=did:sov:3WzFTEzmU95mAF4CHHi9np
```